# Trouble with image gallery on codepen

Tags: html, css, gallery

I'm trying to do my first project in html & css but am having some trouble. I'm practicing using codepen and my gallery was going somewhat well but I'm trying to add the last line of images and it seems to be messing EVERYTHING up and I don't know why. Would anyone mind taking a look?

Here's the [link](http://codepen.io/zenturtle/pen/ezDGC)

For some reason, when I try to add that chess board it all goes bad.

I'm still very new at this so I look forward to learning a lot.

Thanks.

```
  [1]: http://codepen.io/zenturtle/pen/ezDGC
```

Comment: Thank you for the edit Faiz Ahmed

Comment: What exactly is the issue you're running into?

Answer (score 0):

The margins are causing the issues. When you use margins to position an element you push the elements around it too.

One solution is to use: `position: relative` and then use the positioning properties: `top`, `bottom`, `left`, `right`

Example:

```
#chess {
    position: relative;
    left: 555px;
}
```

Another solution is to use `position: absolute`.

1. Place `position: relative` on the `<div id="perimeter">`
2. Place `position: absolute` on each `<img>`
3. Position each `<img>` where you want itwithin the `<div id="perimeter">`

Example:

```
 #chess {
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 122px;
     right: 230px;
 }
```

That's how you'd position the chess image where you want it.

CSS Tricks has a good 
[article](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/) explaining the `position` property.